Creating CRS with pyproj
I'm trying to reimplement code using pyproj, and I thought that this code - is using traverse Mercator projection.
And this is my attempt:
result_lat, result_lon = (52.95863787871814 13.517646600000003)
import pyproj
epsg4326_lat1 = 52.5093259
epsg4326_lon1 = 13.5176466

epsg_4326 = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326)
tmerc = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4(f"+proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0={epsg4326_lat1} +lon_0={epsg4326_lon1} +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs")
tmerc_to_4326 = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(tmerc, epsg_4326, always_xy=True)
result_lon, result_lat = tmerc_to_4326.transform(0, 50000)

But with original implementation:
result_lat, result_lon=(52.958655013752455 13.5176466)
from swri_transform_util.wgs84_transformer import Wgs84Transformer
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

localorigin = PoseStamped()
localorigin.pose.position.x = epsg4326_lon1
localorigin.pose.position.y = epsg4326_lat1
wgst = Wgs84Transformer(localorigin)
result_lat, result_lon = wgst.local_xy_to_wgs84((0, 50000))

Am I missing something? Because there is too big an error in latitude.
